# wp_signon works localhost but not wokrs https site

Tags: login, forms

I made my own login form with using [wp_signon](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/) but i have a problem. It logins perfect in my localhost but not works on my real https web site.

Here is my code.

```
$args = array();
$args[ 'user_login' ] = $_POST[ 'email' ];
$args[ 'user_password' ] = $_POST[ 'password' ];
$args[ 'remember' ] = $_POST[ 'rememberme' ] == '1' ? true : false;

$user = wp_signon( $args, true );
$userID = $user->ID;

wp_set_current_user( $userID, $user->user_login );

if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
    echo '<p class="login-alert">'.$user->get_error_message().'</p>';

} else {
    wp_redirect( admin_url('/') );
    echo '<p class="login-alert">Login success.</p>';
}
```

It prints 'Login success' but it not logins.

Comment: You should `exit();` after the `wp_redirect()` call, then you may `echo` the "Login success." message after the page is reloaded (i.e. cookies are set in the browser).

Comment: Also verify that you do not have caching that interferes with this. When does this code run?

Comment: When i use exit(); after wp_redirect(), it shows empty page after submit. And still not logged in and not redirect.

Comment: @bilimokur where are you redirecting to? Or are you literally called `wp_redirect` with no arguments? If so, that would be why

Comment: @TomJNowell `wp_redirect( admin_url('/') )` with this code i am trying to redirect admin dashboard.

Comment: And is the page that runs `wp_signon` cached in any way? Do you have a cache plugin or something like cloudflare sitting in front of it?

Comment: @bilimokur Try turning on `WP_DEBUG` and check [`wp-content/debug.log`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG) for any errors which may relate to the empty page.

Comment: @SallyCJ here is my debug file https://paste.ee/p/YaEaI

Comment: @TomJNowell i don't use any cache plugin. And trying on private browsing with under clean cookies.

Comment: Maybe the `wp_redirect()` call failed because there has been an output on the page prior to calling `wp_redirect()`.

Comment: @SallyCJ it gives same error without `wp_redirect()`

Comment: You mean the same "Cannot modify header" error? If so, then I'm guessing that your login code works, but maybe a redirect attempt in other code failed. Check your code (the `admin-login.php` file in the theme folder?) for any *other* redirect call(s).

Comment: @SallyCJ login code not works. Because i am chechking it in wp-admin page.

Comment: Yes, you need to call `wp_signon` before anything gets output to the page. The moment even a single character is output, e.g. a header tag, etc, it's too late. cookies need to be sent in the headers and outputting things sends all the headers. Again, you never mentioned when this code is running and where, timing is super important in these things

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you Tom! I put all code before `get_header()` and now all works good. Thank you :)

Comment: @bilimokur I wouldn't put it in a template, but I'd put it in a plugin or `functions.php`, and run it with a check on the `init` hook